# i want to send url on another page throught url

Tags: php

i want to send $c2=@'http://marvelconcepts.net/fb3/02.php?c='.$c.'&&'.'c1='.$c1; on 02.php when i get $C ON 02.php it is not showing full url

```
 <?php
$c='Flower';
$c1='http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1337412470.png';
$c2=@'http://marvelconcepts.net/fb3/02.php?c='.$c.'&amp;&amp;'.'c1='.$c1;
?>
<a href='02.php?c=<?php echo $c; ?>&amp;c1=<?php echo $c1; ?>&amp;c2="<?php echo $c2; ?>"'>share</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You need to urlencode the string.

Comment: Why do you have that `@` in there?

Comment: @ is because it is for diasabling error wamp server eror

Answer (score 4):

Use **urlencode** and **urldecode**.

Refer

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php